# Is it possible to produce purple/ red flames?

Tags: avatar

In (coming soon) episode of Avatar the Last Airbender, we meet the last living dragons. They swirl around Aang and Zuko. Then they unleash the fire of different colors, so is this possible to produce in the world of Avatar bender-wise what I mean is take someone like Azula, for example, would purple and red flames be possible to produce like Azula produces blue flames.

Comment: idk about Avatar specifically, but in real life [anything is possible!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colored_fire) With metal bending you could say they would have to add metals and chemical salts to the flames to color it.

Comment: @Hakase well, I'm only talking about avatar but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Zuko produces flames with some purple and green in Smoke and Shadow part 1:

[image: Zuko proves he is the fire lord with a whirl of flames]

I don't believe he usually firebends like this, however.